# SwifUI - Map() Annotation callout .onTapGesture

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to display a callout for annotations on SwiftUI Map() and am using .onTapGesture and the showCallout boolean to control showing of annotation's text in Text() view element.

Tapping either annotation results in all annotations showing/hiding their Text(), yet the print statement just displays text of the tapped annotation.

How do I do it so only text of the tapped annotation is displayed?

Xcode 15 Beta 2, IOS 17.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let title: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let text: String
    
    init(id: UUID, title: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State var showCallout: Bool = false

    let annotations: [MyAnnotation] = [
        MyAnnotation(id: UUID(), title: "Location 1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64191952505181, longitude: -79.38918661813415), text: "Text 1" ),
        MyAnnotation(id: UUID(), title: "Location 2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64083254041681, longitude: -79.3859357809321), text: "Text 2")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position) {
            ForEach(annotations, id: \.self) { result in
                Annotation(result.title!, coordinate: result.coordinate) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(result.text)
                            .font(.title)
                            .opacity(showCallout ? 1 : 0)

                        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showCallout.toggle()
                                print(result.text)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach where you use `@State var selected: MyAnnotation?` and the corresponding
`.opacity` and `.onTapGesture` logic.

This will display (turn on/off) the `Text` only for the annotation that is tapped.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State var selected: MyAnnotation?  // <-- here
    
    let annotations: [MyAnnotation] = [
        MyAnnotation(id: UUID(), title: "Location 1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64191952505181, longitude: -79.38918661813415), text: "Text 1" ),
        MyAnnotation(id: UUID(), title: "Location 2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64083254041681, longitude: -79.3859357809321), text: "Text 2")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position) {
            ForEach(annotations, id: \.self) { result in
                Annotation(result.title!, coordinate: result.coordinate) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(result.text)
                            .font(.title)
                            .opacity(result.id == selected?.id ? 1 : 0)  // <-- here
                        
                        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selected = (selected == result ? nil : result) // <-- here
                                print(result.text)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```